# Why Is Adding Windows Specific Nugets to ASP.NET Core Possible

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler Nuget description says that it is Windows specific. But I was able to install it on an ASP.NET core project nevertheless.

Shouldn't it be prevented by Visual Studio to add such Windows specific dependencies to an ASP.NET Core project?

Answer (score 2):

If you have only the intentions to release on Windows, why should it be limited?

Of course cross platform is nice, but it isn't mandatory

Comment: I would at least expect a prompt that says that it is not cross-platform. Is there a way to tell this other than reading though its description? I would like to have compile-time check for this.

Comment: I don't think a warning is possible. This kind of information isn't in the nuget package.

Comment: PS.  It's also documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.winhttphandler and I guess the `Win` prefix gives a hint. But have to agree it's far from perfect!